# Runtime error involving sQRY in VBA code to import AccessDB queries to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, vba6

I've been coding a module to import an access database query (hopefully several in the future) into an excel worksheet but keep on getting the same error:

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Syntax error in FROM clause.

The code I am using to import the database query is below:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Dim sQRY As String

Dim strFilePath As String

strFilePath = "P:\DIRT V6-4 W10.accdb"

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";"

sQRY = "SELECT * FROM AIS jobs outstanding"

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

rs.Open sQRY, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing

cnn.Close

Set cnn = Nothing

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Any idea what the issue solution could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AIS jobs outstanding` is causing the error because it contains spaces.

```
sQRY = "SELECT * FROM [AIS jobs outstanding]"
```